# htaccess rewrite using php variables?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First off I'm a complete novice when it comes to htaccess files so forgive me for that.

In short I am trying create a rewite rule that will clean up my urls but wont effect my GET statements. A few examples of what I'm trying to achieve are below:

From: http://www.website.com/job-details.php?jobtitle=project-manager&job_number=JO-1501-2397

to: http://www.website.com/job-details/project-manager-JO-1501-2397

From: http://www.website.com/jobs.php?job_location=Africa

to http://www.website.com/jobs/Africa

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: what have you tried so far? also, for things like 'project-manager-JO-1501-2397', you'd need a way to reliably split that into "project-manager" and "JO-1501-2397". Unless all your jobtitles are two words with a dash every time, I dont know how you'd do that.

Answer (score 0):

create a `.htaccess` file or use apache rewrite: `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html`

The jobdetails.php I suggest you use another url to rewrite.

The rule is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.*)$ jobs.php?job_location=$1
RewriteRule ^job\-details/(.*)/(.*)$ job-details.php?jobtitle=$1&job_number=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

In an htaccess file in your document root, add these rules:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+job-details\.php\?jobtitle=([^&]+)&job_number=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /job-details/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+jobs\.php\?job_location=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /jobs/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^job-details/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /job-details.php?jobtitle=$1&job_number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+)/? /jobs.php?job_location=$1 [L]
```

Note that your URI base will change, so any relative links in your page content will be broken. You'll need to change them all to absolute links to add a base to the page headers:

```
<base href="/" />
```